# Setting Up WAN + LAN Network with pfSense in VirtualBox - Troubleshooting TCP Connection Issue

Tags: networking, firewall, tcp, port-forwarding, virtualbox

**Hello,**

I am currently in the process of configuring a WAN + LAN network within VirtualBox using pfSense (VM) as the router in my LAN. The primary objective is to establish communication between a TCP client program on the host machine (WAN) and a server program on my Ubuntu VM (LAN). All communication is intended to pass through pfSense.

### Issue

I have encountered an issue where the client/server programs, implemented as Python scripts utilizing socket connections, are generating a `Connection refused` error when using the `connect()` function. This suggests a problem with port availability. Let's delve into the details of my setup.

### Network Overview

For my pfSense VM, I have configured two network interfaces: the first is set up as a `bridge`, while the second operates within an `internal network`. My Ubuntu VM is located within the internal network. Promiscuity mode is set to `allow all` on both interfaces.

### pfSense Configuration Overview

My pfSense VM is assigned a static IP address of `192.168.50.1/24`, with DHCP set up for the LAN. Here's a [screenshot of the pfSense configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWsDD.png). On the pfSense dashboard, I have disabled traffic blocking on the WAN interface, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoysm.png). I have added a firewall rule on the WAN interface to allow all requests, while the defaults are maintained for the LAN interface, depicted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lsdd.png). Additionally, I've implemented NAT port forwarding from port `50042` to `50042`, which is used by my client/server program. [Port forwarding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raS4U.png) are illustrated. The remaining settings are at their default values.

### Ubuntu VM Configuration Overview

The network settings for my Ubuntu VM are automatically configured through DHCP. The settings can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQipg.png).

### Routing Overview

All machines within my setup can ping each other and access the internet. A traceroute from my Ubuntu VM to the host machine shows that the path traverses through pfSense, as indicated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdVg.png). However, when attempting a traceroute from the host machine to the Ubuntu VM, the traffic bypasses pfSense, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUPZV.png).

### Additional Tests

I conducted further tests, including altering VirtualBox network interface settings with NAT networking to establish port forwarding directly within VirtualBox. I also experimented with a host-only network and attempted to modify pfSense interface settings. Unfortunately, these attempts disrupted the routing configuration.

I sincerely appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Thank you.